# HTML img distorted until I highlight the image

Tags: html, image, css, firefox, internet-explorer-11

I have a logo in a `<img>` tag and it is made smaller with the following css.

```
#logo{
        position: absolute;
        max-height:82px;
        top: 24px;
        left: 24px;
        height:auto;
        width:auto;
        display:block;
}
```

Image is loaded like this:

```
<img id="logo" src="~/Content/images/OriginalLogo.png" />
```

But something bizarre happens in Firefox when the page loads.

The image looks distorted like this:

[image]

Then when I highlight the image in the browser the distortion goes away:

[image]

I have tried turning off the hardware acceleration on the browser and that did not work.

I used the logo `SVG` as well and same results.

So it must be a software issue, is there a specific way to load an image into `HTML` so Firefox does not do this? Clearly this can not be right because websites would look horrible if all images are distorted like this.

**Note**: This is just a snippet of the logo image, I used windows snipping tool and is for demonstration purposes only.

**UPDATE1**: When using the `SVG` file, the image stays distorted even if I highlight it.

**UPDATE2**: When I open the website in I.E the same thing happens, but with he `.png`logo, even if I highlight it, it still stays distorted.

**UPDATE3**: Tried to load the web page on 3 different machines and the same issue still persisted.

**UPDATE4**: Re-sized the actual image size to the exact size needed and distortion went away. Then tried to just scale the image down from it's original size to half its size, and same problem persists. I don't want to create multiple files of the same image but different sizes.

Comment: Hahaha @RiteshK we can not tell our users / customers what browser to use. I have been developing using Chrome but need to make sure it supports all / most browsers

Comment: Does it work for you to state the height and width as attributes of the image element, rather than in the css?

Comment: You should use photoshop to resize your image, if the problem only happens in firefox its a bug with firefox

Comment: @MichaelCrawford - Tried that, and did not work.

Comment: @KevinBoucher - I Just tried that and it did not work, It actualy stopped me from highlighting the image, so the image was stuck distorted.

Comment: Have you confirmed the problem on a separate computer? You mention changing browser settings like hardware acceleration, which means you will should rule out your own configuration first.

Comment: try different versions of firefox as well.  That doesn't mean you won't have to find a way to work around it, but if you can identify specific versions of FF that work and that don't work, your isolation would help Firefox's developers to fix the problem.

Comment: Also: how big is the image you're trying to scale down?

Comment: @scronide - 1400 x 671, its a image file we paid for and downloaded.

Comment: Tried on 3 different computers and exactly the same result, 2 windows machines, and 1 Mac.

Comment: Re-sized the image file to the exact size I want and it seemed to solve the problem. But this is not the solution I'm looking for

Comment: Please create a demo for this problem otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I'll pop the link up to the website when I get back to the office tomorrow

Comment: Browsers can struggle downsampling that much. Try resizing it to 2x or 3x at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using moz to resize the image rather than the standard CSS attributes.  For example to resize the image to 50% its width and height as you suggested ...

```
#logo .img {
/* For Firefox specifically */
-moz-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); 

/* For the other browsers */
-ms-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); 
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); 
transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
}
```

I'm not sure it should have any affect on the outcome, but might be worth a try to see if the browser interprets the resize differently.

Comment: Ill give this a try, can you re-size to a specific px tho?

Comment: Unfortunately not, transform is designed for other things than resizing like rotations etc.  Thought it might be a worthwhile exercise to see if every form of resizing was giving you the grief.  I agree with others its odd that it's just one browser.

Comment: It's Firefox and ie. Ie is worse the image stays distorted

Comment: I believe it might have been related to the rendered in the back end of the browser. if the image is too big and you try and resize it, then it distorts. But if you save the image into a smaller resolution it seems to resize at a better quality.